# Loading aggregates on reacting to domain events

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-sourcing, aggregateroot, domain-events

I am implementing an application with domain driven design and event sourcing. I am storing all domain events in a DomainEvents table in SQL Server.

I have the following aggregates:

```
- City
   + Id
   + Enable()
   + Disable()

- Company
   + Id
   + CityId
   + Enable()
   + Disable()

- Employee
   + Id
   + CompnayId
   + Enable()
   + Disable()
```

Each one encapsulates its own domain logic and invariants. I designed them as separate aggregates, because one city may have thousands (maybe more) companies and company may also have very large number of employees. If this entities would belong to the same aggregate I had to load them together, which in most cases would be unnecessary.

Calling Enable or Disable will produce a domain event (e.g. `CityEnabled`, `CompanyDisabled` or `EmployeeEnabled`). These events contain the primary key of the enabled or disabled entity.

Now my problem is a new requirement forcing me to enable/disable all related Companies if a City is enabled/disabled. The same is required for Employees, if a Company is enabled/disabled.

In my event handler, which is invoked if for example `CityDisabled` has occurred
I need to execute `DisableCompanyCommand` for each company belonging to that city.

But how would I know what companies should be affected by that change?

**My thoughts:**

1. Querying the event store is not possible, because I can't use conditions like 'where CityId = event.CityId'
2. Letting the parent know its child ids and putting all child ids in every event the parent produces. Is also a bad idea because the event creator shouldn't care who will consume the events later. So only information belonging to the happening event should be in the event.
3. Executing the `DisableCompanyCommand` for every company. Only the companies having the matching `CityId` would change their state. Even though I would do that asynchronously it would produce a huge overhead loading every company on those events. And also for every company getting disabled the same procedure should be repeated to disable all users.
4. Creating read models mapping ParentIds to ChildIds and loading the childIds according to the parentId in the event. This sounds like the most appropriate solution, but the problem is, how would I know if a new Company is created while I am disabling the existing ones?

I am not satisfied with any of the solutions above. Basically the problem is to determine the affected aggregates for a happened event.

Maybe you have better solutions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing can be resolved by a [Saga/Process manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591569.aspx) that listen to the `CityDisabled` event. Then it finds the `CompanyIds` of all `Companies` in that `City` (by using an existing `Read model` or by maintaining a private state of `CityIds`x`CompanyIds`) and sends each one a `DisableCompany` command.

The same applies to `CompanyDisabled` event, regarding the disabling of `Employee`.

P.S. Disabling a City/Company/Employee seems like CRUD to me, these don't seem terms from a *normal* ubiquitous language, it's not very DDD-ish but I consider your design as being correct in regard to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Do your requirements mean you have to fire a CompanyDisabled event when disabling a city?

If not - and your requirement is just that a disabled city means all companies are disabled, then what you would do is on your city read model projection you'd listen for CityDisabled events and mark the companies disabled in your read model.  (If your requirements are to fire an event for each city then Constantin's answer is good)

Your model is more of a child / parent relationship - its kind of a break in traditional "blue book" thought, but I recommend represent this relationship in your domain with more than a CityId.

In my app something like this would be coded as

```
public Task Handle(DoSomething command, IHandlerContext ctx) 
{
   var city = ctx.For<City>().Get(command.CityId);
   var company = city.For<Company>().Get(command.CompanyId);

   company.DoSomething();
}

public Company : Entity<City>
{

   public void DoSomething()
   {
        // Parent is the City
        if(Parent.Disabled)
            throw new BusinessException("City is disabled");

        Apply<SomethingDone>(x => {
            x.CityId = Parent.Id;
            x.CompanyId = Id;
            ...
        });
   }

}
```

(Psuedo code is NServiceBus style code and using my library Aggregates.NET)

Comment: How do you get access to Parent in DoSomething()? In my understanding, the Parent.Disabled info should be taken from the read model, and then put in to the command.

Comment: In the command handler I'm loading and hydrating first the city entity, then the company entity.  In my library loading an entity off another entity makes the parent/child relationship and allows the children to access the Parent object since city has been hydrated too

Comment: Aren't you following CQRS? There should be a single aggregate root entity per command handling?

Comment: Yes - but its actually a single entity CHANGED per command.  There's nothing wrong with reading extra entities do get information from them (and not change them)

Comment: What about the domain model that must have no public state at all? You can load an extra entity (aggregate), but it will be of no help to you, you cannot read anything from it. [Aggregates by definition are not allowed to reach outside of themselves](http://cqrs.nu/Faq/aggregates). To handle a command, the aggregate being modified uses its own state plus info passed to the domain model from external, if it needs data outside its own boundaries. And you fetch that extra data from the read model.

Comment: I agree with the linked doc - aggregates themselves shouldn't load external data (reach outside themselves).  But there's nothing preventing looking at the state of an aggregate - or in other words, reaching in for a look only.

Comment: Yeah but reading state from another aggregate is only possible if you have acces to it, say if they are in the same service. If the other aggregate is in a different service the only option is to subscribe to its events and create a read model from that. I would always go that way because it is possible to move an aggregate to another service for different reasons. What to do, if you belong to that aggregate? Therefore the better design is to rely on read models in my opinion.

Comment: For reading, I ignore service boundaries.  My command handlers have access to all entities (that are saved to the same eventstore).  If you use different eventstores for different services then yeah you'll need some domain read models saved some place.  But from my perspective, if you are generating an invoice from a sales order - there is no problem loading the sales entity even if you are in the accounting service.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite probable that you don't have to explicitly force rules like '*enable/disable all related Companies if a City is enabled/disabled*' in the domain (write) side at all.

If so, there's no need to disable all Companies when a City is disabled, within the domain. As Charles mentioned in his answer, just introduce a rule that e.g., "a Company is disabled if it is disabled itself (directly) or its City is disabled". The same with Company and its Employees.

This rule should be realized at the read side. A Company in the read model will have 2 properties: the first one is *Enabled* which is directly mapped from the domain; the second one is *EnabledEffective* which is calculatable based on the Company's *Enabled* value and its City's *Enabled* value. When a CityDisabled event happens, the read model's event handler traverses the City's all Companies in the read model and sets their *EnabledEffective* property to *false*; when a CityEnabled event happens, the handler sets the City's every Company's *EnabledEffective* property back to its own *Enabled* value. It is *EnabledEffective* property that you will use in the UI.

The logic can be a bit more complex with CompanyEnabled/CompanyDisabled event handling (in respect to Empoyees) as you must take into account both event info and enabled/disabled status of the host City.

If (effective) enabled/disabled status of a Company/Employee is really needed in the domain side (e.g. affecting the way these aggregates handle their commands), consider taking *EnabledEffective* value from the read side and passing it along with the command object.